# Trying to correctly determine whether numbers are weird

Tags: java, methods, output

Made a program that prints if a number is weird or not. If the number is odd, it's weird. If the number is even and inclusively between 2 and 5, it is not weird. If it's even and inclusively between 6 and 20, it's weird, and if it's even and greater than 20, it's not weird. The problem I'm having here is that instead of the output displaying "This number is weird/not weird", I get "Weird" or "Not Weird" on one line, followed by "This number is 0" if it's even, or "This number is 1" if it's odd.

```
public Weird(int num) 
{       
    n = num;
}

public int EvenOrOdd() 
{
    int check = n % 2;
    int answer = n / 2;
    if (check == 0 && answer >= 2 && answer <= 5) 
    {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }

    else if (check == 0 && answer >= 6 && answer <= 20) 
    {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }

    else if (check == 0 && answer > 20) 
    {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }

    else if (check != 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }
    return check;
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Weird w = new Weird(32);
    Weird a = new Weird(21);
    System.out.println("This number is " + w.EvenOrOdd());
    System.out.println("This number is " + a.EvenOrOdd());

}
```

Comment: You are returning an `int`. You should be returning the `String` that you are currently printing

Comment: In addition, the logic as you describe it seems to imply that if a number is greater than 20, either even _or_ odd, then it is not weird.  Your current logic only labels even numbers greater than 20 as not weird.

Comment: methods in Java should follow the camelCase convention and not PascalCase convention. `EvenOrOdd` --> `evenOrOdd`

Comment: Constructing a `Weird` with an argument that is "Not Weird" is-- for lack of a better word-- weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return that string rather than printing it. In your function, you are returning an int but rather you should write a String. Besides that everything looks good but you can decrease the number of check like below:

```
public Weird(int num) 
{       
    n = num;
}

public String EvenOrOdd() 
{
    int check = n % 2;
    if (check == 1 || (check == 0 && n >= 6 && n <= 20)) {
        return "Weird";
    }else{
        return "Not Weird";
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Weird w = new Weird(32);
    Weird a = new Weird(21);
    System.out.println("This number is " + w.EvenOrOdd());
    System.out.println("This number is " + a.EvenOrOdd());

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the program's working just fine now :}

Answer (score 1):

You actually return `int` which is value of `check` field. This is either 1 or 0.

When you call this line-

```
System.out.println("This number is " + w.EvenOrOdd());
System.out.println("This number is " + a.EvenOrOdd());
```

It prints either `This number is 0` or `This number is 1`.

You can get desired output by two ways-

Way 1-
Change return type of method to void EvenOrOdd() like-

```
public void EvenOrOdd() 
{
    int check = n % 2;
    int answer = n / 2;
    if (check == 0 && n >= 2 && n<= 5) 
    {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }

    else if (check == 0 && n>= 6 && n<= 20) 
    {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }

    else if (check == 0 && n> 20) 
    {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }

    else if (check != 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }
}
```

and call method in main as-

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Weird w = new Weird(32);
    Weird a = new Weird(21);
    w.EvenOrOdd();
    a.EvenOrOdd();

}
```

Way 2- Change return type of method to String as-

```
public String EvenOrOdd() 
{
    int check = n % 2;
    int answer = n / 2;
    if (check == 0 && n>= 2 && n<= 5) 
    {
        return "Not Weird";
    }

    else if (check == 0 && n>= 6 && n<= 20) 
    {
        return "Weird";
    }

    else if (check == 0 && n> 20) 
    {
        return "Not Weird";
    }

    else
    {
        return "Weird";
    }
}
```

And main method remains same-

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Weird w = new Weird(32);
    Weird a = new Weird(21);
    System.out.println("This number is " + w.EvenOrOdd());
    System.out.println("This number is " + a.EvenOrOdd());

}
```

Comment: This is still broken - you need to check `n` instead of `answer`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the program's working just fine now :}

Answer (score 0):

The value you return from a method will kind of "replace" the method call. Because you returned `check`:

```
return check;
```

The calls:

```
System.out.println("This number is " + w.EvenOrOdd());
System.out.println("This number is " + a.EvenOrOdd());
```

are basically:

```
System.out.println("This number is " + 0);
System.out.println("This number is " + 1);
```

You seem to be confused about returning and printing. Your method should look like this:

```
public String EvenOrOdd() 
{
    int check = n % 2;
    int answer = n / 2;
    if (check == 0 && n >= 2 && n <= 5) 
    {
        return "Not Weird";
    }

    else if (check == 0 && n >= 6 && n <= 20) 
    {
        return "Weird";
    }

    else if (check == 0 && n > 20) 
    {
        return "Not Weird";
    }

    else
    {
        return "Weird";
    }
}
```

Now the two calls is basically:

```
System.out.println("This number is " + "Weird");
System.out.println("This number is " + "Not Weird");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the program's working just fine now :}

Comment: @Battle please consider accepting the answer that you think is the best by clicking on that checkmark!